# How to read a matrix with given dimensions in C

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I've looked everywhere, and I can't quite figure this out.  How do you read into C a matrix that has been given the dimensions?  The matrix is in a .dat file that is laid out like this.

2 4

1 2 3 4

9 8 7 6

Obviously the 2 corresponds to rows and 4 to the columns but I don't know how to apply that.  I just need to find a way to get this dat file into my program so let's say i just need to read and print them (I already figured out how to do the matrix multiplication part)

Comment: you can use the fscanf function to read the integers in a for loop

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure this C thing out with not the best of luck lol.

Comment: That tag matrix-multiplication seems a bit wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Since the matrix dimensions are given and assume that you have the data file data.dat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{ 
FILE* file=fopen("data.dat","r");
int x,y;
fscanf(file,"%d %d",&x,&y);
//Read the matrix dimensions
int **A=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*x);
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
 for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
 { 
   A[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*y);
 }
}
//allocate the memory
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
 { 
 for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
 {
   fscanf(file,"%d",&A[i][j]); 
 } 
}
//read the integers skipping whitespaces
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
        free(A[i]);
}
//free the memory we allocated
free(A);
fclose(file)
//close files
return 0; 
}
```

The fscanf first read the first 2 characters that are the dimensions and then malloc the dynamic array.
fscanf then scans all the other integers skipping all the whitespaces.
After we free the memory we dynamically allocated and we close the file.

Compile with flag -std=c99.

Answer (score 0):

something like this: you need this header

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and this is main.cpp code - but I am not sure about fscanf function-but it works exectly like usual scanf.
So:

```
FILE *f;
int ch[8];
f=fopen("a.dat","r"); 
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
fscanf(ch[i][j]);
}
}
fclose(f);
```

Comment: just curious, what is the int ch[8] for?